# Adding data in multiple tables in one shot with a foreign key constraints between them

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a problem where I want to have insert operations on different tables in one transaction. So that if transaction fails, none of table get polluted with in-consistent data.

There is another constraint in the problem. Table-2 has a foreign key relationship with primary key (auto_increment) of Table-1. So when I add new entry in Table-1 and Table-2, I need to add new primary key of Table-1 in new Table-2 entry which is the part of same transaction.

I am using MYSQLDataAdaptor for populating the SB.

Problem statement is bit tricky, please let me know, if we need more clarification on the same.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If you insert data in table 1 then get last identity by LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() and use this id as foreign key in table 2 insert. Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem here is that how do I maintain the DB sanity. Suppose insert in table2 fails, then I need to revert back the entry in table1 as well.

Comment: If you got last table identity then you can clear it right?

Comment: Amit, yes you are right but to maintain the ACID property you need to club all the DB operation in the transaction. I have posted the answer to the question, you can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem using transaction concept.

```
 MySqlDataAdapter [] all_adapters = new MySqlDataAdapter[2];
 DataTable [] data_tables = new DataTable[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    all_adapters[i] = new MySqlDataAdapter(query[i], connection);
    MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(all_adapters[i]);
    all_adapters[i].InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();

    data_tables[i] = new DataTable();
    all_adapters[i].Fill(data_tables[i]);
}

MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
         all_adapters[i].InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;

         if (i == 0)
         {
              ... Add entry in table-1

              // Fetch new auto_increment primary key of table-1
              string new_query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
              MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(new_query, connection);
              int primary_id_table1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
         }
        else 
        {
             ... Add entry in table-2.
             Use primary_id_table1 to populate the foreign key in table-2
        }
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     transaction.Rollback();
}
```

This will make sure that either both the table are updated in the data base simultaneously or none of the tables get updated, as the transaction effect is rolled back. This will help in maintaining the consistency of the database. Hence, maintaining the ACID property among the given transaction.

Comment: How it will maintain when first transaction is not having any transaction attached. Also, you do not need to fire SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() separatly. In your insert command you can write this as last statement, so when insert happens it returns the id. Using loops to achieve what you need is not standard way and errorprone.

Comment: If Adding an entry in table-1 failed, then exception is raised and it it caught to rollback the effect, if any.

Please let me know if it did not answer your query.

How can I get the last inserted ID without executing "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" ?

Comment: Already answered as above. Suppose your query is insert into table(x,y) values(zz,xx); after this query execution just call SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as next sql statement. This should be part of procedure or part of single command. Also, if entry in table-1 failed it will not trigger rollback as no transaction attached to first execution. In addition to this, your original question has been solved. So recommend to open new question or post your code in Stack overflow code review.

Comment: Amit, I agree with you. I have missed one part in the solution, where I have attached the transaction with the command. Now I have edit my solution. It should answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible only if you keep track of Table-1 primary key and generate your inserts with pre-calculated primary key. So you must be sure, no one can't insert same time any data into same table.

Answer (score 0):

I scratched my head over this one for quite a while until I finally realized the issue. I was attempting to update two primary tables with autoincrementing ID fields and then update a third table with the values of the IDs from the records from the first two tables, all within a transaction. I found that the AutoIncrement Primary Key fields in a dataset won't be the actual value of the records written after an update (their fields will have values, but not necessarily the correct ones). It will just be the next in the sequence from the seed value, when the table schema is read.  So to handle this, add a RowUpdated Handler to your DataAdapter and read the command.LastInsertedId property. That way the AutoIncrement values are the actual values written in the table. Then adding the new records to the third table works.

```
{
    MySqlDataAdapter daAll = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from courses;Select * from productsku;Select * from productcourseassociation;", sqlConn);
    MySqlDataAdapter daCourses = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from courses;", sqlConn);
    MySqlDataAdapter daSku = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from productsku;", sqlConn);
    MySqlDataAdapter daAssoc = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from productcourseassociation;", sqlConn);
    daCourses.RowUpdated += DaCourses_RowUpdated;
    daSku.RowUpdated += DaSku_RowUpdated;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daAll.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);

    daCourses.TableMappings.Add("courses", "Table");
    daSku.TableMappings.Add("productsku", "Table1");
    daAssoc.TableMappings.Add("productcourseassociation", "Table2");
    ForeignKeyConstraint fkConstraint1 = new ForeignKeyConstraint("fk1", ds.Tables[0].Columns["courseid"], ds.Tables[2].Columns["courseid"]);
    ForeignKeyConstraint fkConstraint2 = new ForeignKeyConstraint("fk2", ds.Tables[1].Columns["skuid"], ds.Tables[2].Columns["skuid"]);
    ds.Tables[2].Constraints.Add(fkConstraint1);
    ds.Tables[2].Constraints.Add(fkConstraint2);

    MySqlCommandBuilder cbCourses = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daCourses);
    MySqlCommandBuilder cbSku = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daSku);
    MySqlCommandBuilder cbAssoc = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daAssoc);

    DataRow courseRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    courseRow["coursename"] = courseName;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(courseRow);

    r = ds.Tables[1].NewRow();
    r["skudesc"] = courseName;
    r["duration"] = 1;
    ds.Tables[1].Rows.Add(r);

    r = ds.Tables[1].NewRow();
    r["skudesc"] = courseName;
    r["duration"] = 3;
    ds.Tables[1].Rows.Add(r);

    r = ds.Tables[1].NewRow();
    r["skudesc"] = courseName;
    r["duration"] = 12;
    ds.Tables[1].Rows.Add(r);        

    daCourses.Update(ds, "Table");
    daSku.Update(ds, "Table1");     
    daAssoc.Fill(ds, "Table2");

    int courseId = Convert.ToInt32(courseRow["courseid"]);
    DataRow[] skurows = ds.Tables[1].Select(String.Format("skudesc='{0}'", courseName));
    foreach (DataRow dr in skurows)
    {
        r = ds.Tables[2].NewRow();
        r["skuid"] = dr["skuid"];
        r["courseid"] = courseId;
        ds.Tables[2].Rows.Add(r);
    }
    daAssoc.Update(ds, "Table2");
}   

private void DaSku_RowUpdated(object sender, MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row updated");
    e.Row["skuid"] = e.Command.LastInsertedId;
}

private void DaCourses_RowUpdated(object sender, MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row updated");
    e.Row["courseid"] = e.Command.LastInsertedId;
}
```